# Case when LEN > 10

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Afternoon All,

I'm currently trying to write a case when statement that replaces anything over 12 characters as a '' . Cant seem to get the right syntax and wondered if anyone has any pointers?

```
CASE WHEN Field1 = LEN(Field1) >12 THEN '' ELSE Field1 END
```

Thanks

Comment: Try CASE WHEN LEN(Field1) >12 THEN '' ELSE Field1 END

Comment: Worked Perfect - Thank you Mike

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the `Field1 =` part right after the `WHEN` (the part between `WHEN` and `THEN` must be a boolean expression ONLY). I'm guessing you want that outside the `CASE` expression altogether since you can't do assignments inside a `CASE` expression.

```
Field1 = CASE LEN(Field1) > 12 THEN '' ELSE Field1 END
```